# 2-dimensional array to 1-dimensional array convertion

Tags: php, yii2

With my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT number.phone_number FROM number, ordered_number WHERE ordered_number.number_id=number.id AND ordered_number.order_id=$id";
    $connection = \Yii::$app->getDb();
    $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
    $numery = $command->queryAll();
```

I get array that looks like this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'phone_number' => string '546732354' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'phone_number' => string '565345456' (length=9)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'phone_number' => string '456557546' (length=9)
```

I want to get simple array, where the first element is just the number (here - the string), without name 'phone_number' and additional 1-element arrays inside the main array. When I try to do foreach on this array, it tells me that I use "Illegal offset type". I found that it means I'm using object, instead of an array, but that's an array, not an object and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: BTW you should use Query builder because you are open to SQL injection now. Something like `$sql = (new Query())->from('number')->select('phone_number')->leftJoin('ordered_number', ['ordered_number.number_id' => 'number.id'])->where(['ordered_number.order_id' => $id])->all();`

Comment: I know, but I had to many problems, and I spent WHOLE day trying to do that. No results. I asked question about that on stack yesterday.
And I used exactly what you've written, but the result was null, while shouldn't be :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even simplier (but for php5.5 and php7):

```
$numery = array_column(
    $command->queryAll(),
    'phone_number'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below loop to get desired result

```
$numery = $command->queryAll();
$number_arr = array();
foreach($numery as $number)
{
   array_push($number_arr,$number['phone_number']);
}
print_r($number_arr);
```